# Which time zone does the timestamps are written on retweets

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to understand when a tweet is retweeted. To do that I learnt how to use twitter API and tweetpy. This is the first time I use both of them.

I got the retweet I am interested by using the following line at the end:

```
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        auth_api = API(auth)
        tweetid= # this is the id of the original tweet
        auth_api.retweets(tweetid)[0].created_at
```

Now, when I look at the output I see `datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 28, 15, 44, 56)` this result. However, I cannot see the timezone this timestamp belongs. How can I know that according to which time zone is this written ?

Comment: It looks like you've got a "naive" datetime rather than an "aware" one, which has a tzinfo structure attached. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) for details. I'm not familiar with the Twitter API, but if you're lucky, your timestamps are in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object `created_at` is a string attribute with the value of "UTC time when this Tweet was created."