# Which objects UTC code does Status.getCreatedAt() return for a retweet?

Tags: java, twitter4j

possible duplicate 
[Which time zone does the timestamps are written on retweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571638/which-time-zone-does-the-timestamps-are-written-on-retweets)

I am making a SaveSpace counter of top 10 hashtags per day from twitter json files.

here I pass a line from a file stream. check to see if the day has changed, if its changed i created

I have accumulated 3 days worth of tweeters from concatenating 3 days worth I downloaded out of a month worth off archive.org

Unfortunately I get the if (...cur.isAfter(prev)) triggering 7 or so times so I wonder what is going on

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(twitterFormat, Locale.ENGLISH);
sf.setLenient(true);
....
curStatus = TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(line);
Instant cur = sf.parse(curStatus.getCreatedAt().toString()).toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
if (prev != null && cur.isAfter(prev)) 
{
//save my TreeMap of HashTags and the create a new one

}
...
///save hashtags
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out my data source wasn't ordered by createdAt json field
This happened because when I used find -name '*.json' on cat to recursively concatenate the json files embedded in folders from the torrent of tweets the find results didn't come back in numerical order which was fixed with a | sort -n | command as the file paths went day/hour/minute.json

commands I used

```
find ./ -name '*.json' | sort -n | xargs cat > ../final.json
```

and

```
awk 'NR%10==0' final.json > prun.json
```

to get an even spread 10% of the file

https://archive.org/details/archiveteam-twitter-stream-2013-08